# Hiding overflow if clicked anywhere except for the button

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a section of my website that has a fixed position and has a bootstrap drop down menu inside of it. The issue I was having was that when you clicked on the menu the content was being cut off the page. To solve this I wanted to add an overflow scroll to the fixed section, but only when the element is clicked.

I have this partially working to where if you click on the element and the menu is opened then the overflow appears and if you click on the element again then the overflow hides again. this is what my code looks like

```
$('.dropMenu').on('click', function(){
    if($(this).find('.dropdown').hasClass('open')){
        $('.sideContent').css('overflow', 'hidden');
    }else {
        $('.sideContent').css('overflow', 'scroll');
    }
  });
```

My issue is that if you click anywhere else on the page the overflow is still there and I would like it to disappear. Is there anyway to do this?

A quick fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/6r2qJ/

Comment: try using `'focus'` instead of `'click'`, then `.on()` `'blur'`, hide the overflow again.

Comment: the overflow won't come up at all if I use focus...

Comment: Can you post the relevant html as well?

Comment: the html will be of no help other that to tell you that I have a ul with a class of dropMenu

Comment: And .dropdown is a <li>?

Comment: yes, it's a bootstrap menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try focusout:

```
$('.dropMenu').on('click', function(){

    if($(this).find('.dropdown').hasClass('open')){
        $('.sideContent').css('overflow', 'hidden');
    }else {
        $('.sideContent').css('overflow', 'scroll');
    }
}).on('focusout', function(){

        $('.sideContent').css('overflow', 'hidden');

});
```

here is the fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/6r2qJ/3/

Comment: When you click on the drop down menu the .sidecontent's css changes to overflow:scroll; and then if you either click on the button or anywhere else effectively closing the menu it then changes the overflow to overflow:hidden;

Comment: That was honestly a typo in the fiddle because I created it so quickly. It is not that way on the actual site. I'm working on a billion other things right now trying to meet a deadline. That unfortunately won't work because on my page I have so many more elements and I can't have twenty to thirty different click functions. That was why I kind of wanted the function to be everything except that button.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).click(function () {
    $('.sideContent').css('overflow', 'hidden');
});

$('.dropdown').click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

If i undestand you correctly this may help. event.stopPropagation() forbid closing menu if you clicked on button $('.dropdown'), othercase it will close.

Comment: ...I want it to close. I just want the overflow to go away if clicked away from the menu. And I have tried document, but because the button is within the document it overrides the click I do want to happen.

Comment: `event.stopPropagation();` is supposed to prevent the clicks you do want from being overridden.   Did you already try using his suggestion in your code?

Comment: Yes, I did. It breaks the drop down menu all together because you are telling it to stop opening and closing the menu.